How do I get some kind of warning or indication before the screen locks in macOS?
In macOS I have fairly short times for auto-screen-lock (2-min on battery, 5-min on power), with immediate password requirement of course, for security. I usually lock manually, but these are there as a backup.
However, because the lock is instant, it means there are occasions when it locks when I don't want it to. For example I'm reading code and thinking, or I stopped to look in a book then looking back to the screen.
I'd like a warning before the screen locks, for example fade down to 50% then wait 5s before actually locking. I think it may already do this when on single-screen (laptop-only), but it doesn't happen when using external monitors.
If I had such a feature:

My deep thought would never be interrupted by having to unlock.
I could set the auto-lock times both down to 1 minute (only reason I choose 2+5 is because it's a compromise to minimise unwanted locking, but it still sometimes happens).

If anyone knows of a way to get such a warning/indication before screen-lock, please let me know.

So what warning do you get?

Your title is "Why do I get a warning", but the body reads "how can I get a warning?". Which is it? Also, what security scenario is a 2-minute lock preventing? It's annoying, and not actually making your laptop more secure.

@benwiggy Someone edited the title and completely changed the meaning. Question is "how". The scenario is: Someone approaches, asks question/help I turn away to see if I can help, without locking because I'm still at my desk, then it turns out this issue needs me to go somewhere else. If I'm distracted this way and get into a short chat, I'm more likely to forget to lock as I get up to go elsewhere. In this case a shorter time means screen will lock. Also, I notice when it locks and it triggers my "If a colleague-supporting chat takes longer than 2-minutes, go help them solve it now!" rule.

Apparently, you can write a Swift script that will respond to willSleepNotification event. "An observer of this message can delay sleep for up to 30 seconds while handling this notification." https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/1530075-willsleepnotification

You can set it to require a password 5 seconds after locking, "Require password [immediately] after sleep" inside System Prefs > Security & Privacy. Change that to "5 seconds"
